# Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm trying to write tests for my node.js API but they keep failing with the above error. I'm running mongodb in a docker instance and mongoose as driver.

So far i've tested that the connection to mongodb is fine, since i can fetch all posts inside the tests with Post.find({}). The problem is that the tests are stuck at Post.create(). See the code below:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const app = require('../../app'); // Import your Express app
const Post = require('../../models/Post');

const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Posts', () => {
  describe('Posts Controller Tests', () => {
    it('should get a specific post by ID', async (done) => {
      // const posts = await Post.find({})
      // console.log(posts) prints all posts

      const postData = { title: "title" }
      // code hangs on this line
      const post = await Post.create(postData)

      chai.request(app)
        .get(`/api/v1/posts/${post._id}`)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(res).to.have.status(200);
          expect(res.body.id).to.equal(post._id);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried all solutions where everyone keeps suggesting to increase the mocha timeout, but that's  not the issue here. Also, i have seen many examples creating mongodb connection inside the tests, but it doesn't makes sense coz i m already creating a mongodb connection in the app.js file.